# vitest react-testing-library: how to test xlsx file upload and handling?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, jsdom, vitest

i have a react component where the user can *select* a xlsx file and that [parses it](https://gitlab.com/catamphetamine/read-excel-file) and shows the data in a table.
and i would like to create a simple *end-to-end* test for it:

- upload a known xlsx file from disc
- check that the known data is rendered in the table

i have three questions regarding this

- with the below code the excel parsing does not work
  iam unsure if iam doing the file reading correctly -
  and if there is any *nicer* vite / vitest build in import/loading function for such a use case?
- (if the parsing would work) is the *waitFor* the correct way? / do i need the extra *act* to trigger the rerender?
- as iam new to testing - is my idea of the test in any way meaningful? or are there better ways to accomplish this?

```js
import { act, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

import MyImportFile from ".";


import path from "node:path";
import { openAsBlob } from "node:fs";

describe("MyImportFile", () => {
  test("does the upload work?", async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    render(<MyImportFile />);

    expect(screen.getByText(/person_forename/i)).toBeInTheDocument();

    const input = screen.getByLabelText(/Import XLSX/i);
    expect(input).toBeInTheDocument();

    console.log("__dirname", __dirname);
    const xlsx_file_path = path.join(__dirname, "people_10_min.xlsx");
    // const xlsx_file_path_abs = path.resolve(xlsx_file_path);
    let blob = undefined;
    try {
      blob = await openAsBlob(xlsx_file_path, {
        type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

    console.log("blob", blob);
    // https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act
    await act(async () => {
      /* fire events that update state */
      await user.upload(input, blob);
    });

    //const data_content = await vi.waitFor(() => screen.getByText(/Friedmann/i));
    //expect(data_content).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

i have created a [*more or less* minimal example at codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/mrt2-load-excel-file-zqmtt7?workspaceId=d4857c0b-8f38-423b-84b8-33db6722c766&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt78ys1f00082067blb3yr76%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B44.40749464693964%252C55.59250535306036%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt78ys1f00032067jkaxutan%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt78ys1f000520670z4agbxk%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt78ys1f00072067yscqmdop%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clt78ys1f00032067jkaxutan%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt78ys1f00032067jkaxutan%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clt78ys1f00072067yscqmdop%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt78ys1f00072067yscqmdop%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt9330d601vc2067gps4ph2a%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt78ys1f00062067244p8kea%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3001%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522SANDBOX_INFO%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt8e7zjw002c2067wojye63q%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3001%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt9330d601vc2067gps4ph2a%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clt78ys1f000520670z4agbxk%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt78ys1f000520670z4agbxk%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt92y2kj019w206743l0gd9w%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clt930hmc001gdhiph9qvfof3%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt93354d01y02067f83jr09o%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clt93357v001jdhip84i2gzy9%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt93354d01y02067f83jr09o%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

and hope to learn a bunch of things :-)

i also posted question relating this to

- https://github.com/vitejs/vite/pull/15651
- https://gitlab.com/catamphetamine/read-excel-file/-/issues/90

Answer (score 0):

solved - with using [vite-plugin-arraybuffer](https://github.com/tachibana-shin/vite-plugin-arraybuffer):
for the file loading.

then i could

```js
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

import MyImportFile from ".";

import xlsx_file from "../../../dev_tests/people_10.xlsx?arraybuffer";

describe("MyImportFile", () => {
    test("does the upload work?", async () => {
        const user = userEvent.setup();
        render(
            <MyImportFile />
        );

        expect(screen.getByText(/person_forename/i)).toBeInTheDocument();

        const input = screen.getByLabelText(/Import XLSX/i);
        expect(input).toBeInTheDocument();
        await user.upload(input, xlsx_file);
        const data_content = await screen.getByText(/^Friedmann/i)
        expect(data_content).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

they key was to strip out all Blob and File in between steps.
as the promised based `blob.arrayBuffer()` did not resolve correctly..
(i missed or did not get the await for this correctly..)
therefore the [fflate got an empty array: resulting in `Error: invalid zip data`](https://gitlab.com/catamphetamine/read-excel-file/-/blob/master/source/read/unpackXlsxFileBrowser.js?ref_type=heads#L24)

---

### How i got there:

got there on a very long journey - i tested a bunch of things

- different plugins and loading / importing versions for the file
- converting the file to a base64 representation and store this as javascript file
- this way i could load it in the browser to cross test that the base64 and back decoding to a file did run fine
- so i could exclude errors on my site and track down to browser / node.js
- found i had to import `import { Blob } from "node:buffer";` to get the Blob creation to work for me
- but this did not solve the [`Error: invalid zip data`](https://gitlab.com/catamphetamine/read-excel-file/-/issues/90)
- tracked down where the error [came from in the code](https://gitlab.com/catamphetamine/read-excel-file/-/blob/master/source/read/unpackXlsxFileBrowser.js?ref_type=heads#L24)
- recreated this part in my test case to look at every single step
- found basically the `.arrayBuffer()` did not resolve.
- so back to the beginning.. clean up all (see above.)